# How to do the following command in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

My table:

```
Series  Valve  Poles  Wires
1       2      3      4
1       nan    z      3
1       2      3      4
2       q      e      z
2       b      4      nan
3       nan    2      a
4       1      2      3
4       nan    4      5
5       nan    2      1
5       1      2      nan
```

I want to apply following rules:

- Do not display or select rows where all the column values are fulfilled.
- For example: for the Column Series we have one row which has all three values. So we should leave the rows where Column Series is equal to 1 because there is one row which has all three values.
- Display or Select that Column Series where in any of its rows all three values are not fulfilled.

I want the output 1: where above condition satisfied.
So the output will be Series 3 and 5 in an array.
And 2nd Output will be the remaining.

I was first printing the Null value rows:

```
Bank_Det_Null = Bank_Det[Bank_Det.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

and then I was saving the Series or LIFNER here:

```
Bank_Det_Null_LIFNR = Bank_Det_Null[['LIFNR']].values.ravel()
```

And then again I was passing those values for seeing the row:

```
df_LFBK.loc[df_LFBK.LIFNR.isin(Bank_Det_Null_LIFNR)].head()
```

But still I was not getting what I want.

Comment: Can you show your efforts, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Please add also an expected output.

Comment: @Fabio I have added what I have written.

Comment: @EdChum I have added my efforts please see here I am just not able to do what I want thats why I posted here.

Comment: I just want an array having values 3 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` on 'Series' and `filter` on your condition:

```
In [121]:
df.groupby('Series').filter(lambda x: (x.isnull().any(axis=1)).all())

Out[121]:
   Series Valve Poles Wires
5       3   NaN     2     a
8       5   NaN     2     1
9       5     1     2   NaN
```

Comment: But @EdChum I want Series with 5 displayed only once. Is it possible

Comment: You'll have to define which and why otherwise call `drop_duplicates(subset='Series')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.